# How to use Ajax with CherryPy to run a python script to SSH into a Raspberry Pi Zero from a web interface

Tags: python, ajax, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a web interface to remotely control a GoPro. To do this so far, I've got a Raspberry Pi 3B which I'm planning to use  as a web server which is connected to a Pi Zero via USB, which is connected via WiFi to the GoPro. So, whenever I SSH into the Pi Zero from the Pi 3B, I can control the GoPro. So now, I'm wanting to create a web server with CherryPy and Ajax so that I can create a web interface to control the GoPro when connected to the same WiFi network as the Pi 3B (web server).

I've been reading the [CherryPy documentation](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-8-make-it-smoother-with-ajax) to try and understand how to use Ajax with CherryPy. I was able to implement it before with a more basic CherryPy method (without Ajax), but it made it go onto a different webpage whereas for this, I want it to stay on the same webpage, which is why I'm using Ajax. I've never really used Ajax before so I'm quite unfamiliar and I basically tried my best to replicate the example on the CherryPy documentation but that didn't work, so forgive me if I'm missing something simple here.

Here's the HTML page code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#takePhotos").click(function(e){
            $.post("/take", {"count": $("input[name='count']").val()})
            .done(alert("Running Take Photos!"));
            })
            e.preventDefault();
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="" name="count"/>
    <button id="takePhotos">Take Photos</button>
</body>
```

And here's the python code for the web server:

```
import cherrypy
import os, os.path
import GoPro as gp
import requests


class RaspiServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
    return open('index.html')

@cherrypy.expose
class GPWebService(object):
@cherrypy.tools.accept(media="text/plain")
def GET(self,count):
    print("running")

def POST(self,count):
    print("running")
    gp.connect("pi", "raspberrypizero.local", "raspberry")
    gp.takePhotos(count)
    return count


if __name__ == '__main__':
conf = {
    '/': {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

    },
    '/takePhotos':{
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content_Type', 'text/plain')]

    },
    '/static':{
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': "./public"
    }
}
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'})
webapp = RaspiServer()
webapp.takePhotos = GPWebService()
cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I enter a value into the input field and click the button, the alert shows up saying 'Running Take Photos!' and in the console I can see that the web server has received the request, but the python scripts don't run in the 'POST' method. 
What I want to happen is that the POST method executes and the two python methods 'connect' and 'takePhotos' execute (which is not happening right now).

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing about and learning more about Ajax all morning, I finally figured out the answer and it's as stupid and easy as I thought.

On line 7 of the index.html file, I had to change `$.post("/take")` to `$.post("/takePhotos")`